# Syntax error: Unclosed identifier literal at [2:2]

Tags: google-bigquery

```
CREATE TABLE
 'bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules_partitioned'
PARTITION BY
  YEAR(year)  AS
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules`
```

Some one help me clarify the error here.

Comment: to address this syntax error - use backticks around `bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules_partitioned` - not apostrophe! Also, note: you will not be able to create any table in public dataset - you should use your own instead!

Comment: Also, if you're creating a table, you should do it in your dataset :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `year` field is not a string. It has to be data of type `date` to partition in GCP. Also, you do not need the apostrophe (') at the beginning and end of the new table, only the `FROM` table:

```
CREATE TABLE bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules_partitioned
PARTITION BY
  YEAR(year)  AS
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules`
```